# Prevent Duplicate Records in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I have 3 tables in my Database, one for student and other for the courses and the third one to store what every student select from courses. I want to prevent the student from selecting the same course more than once. what condition should I provide in Insert statement in the third table?

Thanks

Comment: welcome to StackOverflo. Please  have a look on [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is really not a valid question.  It is your business logic.  I know very well this needs a one method call GetvaluefromtableByuserId(userid) then one if condition.  It is such a simple one.

Comment: You need to add a unique constraint in StudentId, CourseId OR if you cannot change table design, you need to check if the record already exists before you insert - if not exists (select 1 from StudentCourse where StudentId = @StudentId and CouseId=@CourseId) BEGIN --Insert here -- END

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your StudentCourse table should have a unique constraint on the (StudentId, CourseId) table.

As an alternative, you can create the Primary Key on your StudentCourse table as a composite key on (StudentId, CourseId).

Comment: Yeah Thanks that's work, uniqe constraint do the job

Answer (score 1):

While it follows that every table in your database must have a Primary key constraint, often its an auto generated value useful when carrying out most database maintenance tasks. However the primary key itself will  not protect you from user generated or user captured data that may contain duplications. Enter the “Unique” constraint! This is a very powerful table-level constraint that you can apply to your table against a chosen table column, which can greatly assist to prevent duplicates in your data. For example, say you have a “Users” table and in it, you have an EmailAddress column, surely it would be strange to capture 1 or 2 users who have an identical email address.